# How to change emmet shortcut key in netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, shortcut, emmet

In netbeans(7.4) I installed **emmet** plugin.
I have to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to trigger code completion.
I want to replace it with <kbd>tab</kbd> key.
I searched <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> in keymap in the **option**->**keymap**. There isn't one.
Why? I can trigger code completion with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> though.
How can I set it to <kbd>tab</kbd> key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the plugin page at [GitHub](https://github.com/emmetio/netbeans), it says to go to `Tools > Options > Keymap`

Comment: Thanks. I finally found that 'category' and repalce the shortcut with tab. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac the path to go is `NetBeans > Preferences > Keymap`.

Answer (score 0):

By default **Expand Abbreviation**  shortcut key:

> Ctrl + Alt + N

Open Netbeans > Tools > Options > Keymap > Search (Press Ctrl + Alt + N) and You will see it

[image]

I know its pretty late